# How to import an hdb file

Tags: python, matlab, import

I am trying to analyse some images collected with a neutron detector. These are in an hdb format; do you know how could I import such files file in Matlab or Python?

Comment: What the heck is an "hdb file"? Could you elaborate on this? I've never heard of this format before and I doubt it's a Nero HD Backup if you're using a neutron detector to generate them.

Comment: I have no idea of what the file is. I just got an .hdb file mailed ;-)

Comment: What does the hbd file look like? Could you include an example?